# Menu elements can be clicked around the menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu, that by clicking on one of its element it does a moving animation plus highlights the clicked element,alongside changes in opacity when hovering over an element. However i noticed that if i click around the menu and not an on element or hover the mouse around it, the menu animations (moving of the elements is activated, highlight of a click, and hovering opacity) all three are activated. Any help?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kvey3d12/)

HTML:

```
<div id="menu" class="menu">
   <ul class="headlines">
      <li id="item1"><button>aa</button></li>
      <li id="item2"><button>A</button></li>
      <li id="item3"><button>B        </button></li>
      <li id="item4"><button>C         </button></li>
      <li id="item5"><button>D   </button></li>
      <li id="item6"><button>E       </button></li>
      <li id="item7"><button>F       </button></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding-top: 8px;
    text-align:center;
    border-style: none;
}


.menu li {
    position: relative;
    top: 180px;
    left: 0px;
}
#item7 {
    transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .8s, left .8s ease-out;
    margin-left:105px 
}
#item6 {
    transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s, left 1s ease-out;
    margin-left: 95px;
}
#item5 {
    transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.2s, left 1.2s ease-out;
    margin-left: 60px;
}
#item4 {
    transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.4s, left 1.4s ease-out;
    margin-left: 123px;
}
#item3 {
    transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.6s, left 1.6s ease-out;
    margin-left: 113px;
}
#item2 {
    transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1.8s, left 1.8s ease-out;
    margin-left: 130px;
}
#item1 {
    transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s, left 2s ease-out;
    margin-left: 117px;
}

#item1>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item2>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item3>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item4>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item5>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item6>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}
#item7>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;font-size: 1em;}

.permahover li {
    opacity: 1;
    left: -33%;
}
.headlines li {
    font-size:1.5em;
    color:#000000;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.headlines:hover li, .headlines.active li {
    /* PARENT HOVER */
    opacity:0.4;
    cursor: pointer;
    /* Dim all */
}
.headlines li:hover, .headlines li.active {
    /* SINGLE HOVER */
    opacity: 1;
    /* Max one */
    color:#000000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".menu").on("click", function () {
  $(".menu").addClass('permahover');

});


 var $li = $('.headlines li').click(function() {
    var state = !$(this).hasClass('active');
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('active', state);

    $li.removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active', state);
});
```

Comment: you can set the width of every li elements to 0px and play with margin-left to put them whereever you want https://jsfiddle.net/kvey3d12/10/

Comment: @AndreiMaieras the problems are still there in the jsfiddle you linked

Comment: Sorry, try now, i've updated the link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kvey3d12/11/ i just add `button` to your query selector.  so it only animated when you click on the button it self... is that what you mean?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kvey3d12/12/ combined with wlin's answer, so the hand selector appears only when mouse above the button, same the click event is raised only when you click on the button(letter here)

Answer (score 0):

It is because the li Elements are Block-Elements and taking all it´s available horizontal space.

Try to set display:inline-block; and positioning them different or giv them a width.

See picture below:
[image: Jsfiddle Developer Console <li> highlight]

Answer (score 0):

Add style `display: inline-block` to `li`s and put them into `div`s.

http://jsfiddle.net/kvey3d12/13/